# slide-toggling an element that has no height and padding only without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

In jQuery, there is this method called `.slideToggle()` that magically slides up and down an element regardless of its height and padding; I want to achieve the same without using that library, so I made 2 experiments: One has an element that has height and the other one has an element that has no height set, only formed by padding.

Experiment 1 (has height):

```js
document.querySelector('#experiment-1 > button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('slideToggle');
})
```

```css
#experiment-1 > button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#experiment-1 > .box {
  background: #eee;
  color: #aaa;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 3s linear;
}

#experiment-1 > .box.slideToggle {
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section id="experiment-1">
  <button>Slide Toggle</button>
  <div class="box">
    <span>Experiment 1</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Experiment 2 (padding only):

```js
document.querySelector('#experiment-2 > button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('slideToggle');
})
```

```css
#experiment-2 > button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#experiment-2 > .box {
  background: #eee;
  color: #aaa;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5rem;
  transition: all 3s linear;
}

#experiment-2 > .box.slideToggle {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section id="experiment-2">
  <button>Slide Toggle</button>
  <div class="box">
    <span>Experiment 2</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

In experiment 1, I think it's almost perfect, only that when the box is almost closed, the text still has overflow, I set the trasition duration to 3 seconds to make it more obvious.

In experiment 2, the only problem is the box slides diagonally, not vertically.

How can I make these two work perfectly without using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

## `overflow: hidden`

Adding `overflow: hidden` to `#experiment-1 > .box` will hide the `<span>`s text when the `<div>` is *shorter* than its height.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the second example, simply change the line

```
padding: 0;
```

to read

```
padding: 0 5rem;
```

That will keep the box from getting narrower as it gets shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

1. For first and second experiment change  [`overflow:hidden`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) form `overflow:0`

```js
document.querySelector('#experiment-1 > button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('slideToggle');
})
```

```css
#experiment-1 > button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#experiment-1 > .box {
  background: #eee;
  color: #aaa;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 3s linear;
}

#experiment-1 > .box.slideToggle {
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section id="experiment-1">
  <button>Slide Toggle</button>
  <div class="box">
    <span>Experiment 1</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

1. For the second the [`padding:5rem 5rem`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding.asp) reduce only the padding of top and bottom like `padding:0 5rem`

```js
document.querySelector('#experiment-2 > button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('slideToggle');
})
```

```css
#experiment-2 > button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#experiment-2 > .box {
  background: #eee;
  color: #aaa;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5rem 5rem;
  transition: all 3s linear;
}

#experiment-2 > .box.slideToggle {
  padding: 0 5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section id="experiment-2">
  <button>Slide Toggle</button>
  <div class="box">
    <span>Experiment 2</span>
  </div>
</section>
```